Examples showing Rellich-Kondrakov theorem fails for domains with non-Lipschitz boundary?
The Rellich-Kondrakov theorem requires the domain to have Lipschitz boundary, but after searching in many places, I have not found an example to show that this is necessary.
Can anyone share an example or a reference? Many thanks.

In dimension 2, if you pull off the half-segment $\{1/2\}\times(0,1/2]$ from the square $(0,1)^2$ you obtain an open set $\Omega$ which does not satisfy the lipschitz condition (nor the cone condition). This kind of "fissure" domains are helpful to test the necessity of the cone condition. More precisely, if $B$ is a small ball around $(1/2,0)$ (say of radius $1/4$), its intersection with $\Omega$ as two connected components (one at the left of the above half-segment, another one on the right). Now you can easily find a smooth function $f\in\mathscr{C}^\infty(\Omega)$ equaling $1$ one on the first connected component of $B\cap \Omega$ and $0$ on the other one, with all derivatives bounded. This already tells you that no $W^{1,1}(\mathbf{R}^2)$ extension of $f$ is possible even though $f$ belongs to all Sobolev spaces $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ for $p\in[1,\infty]$.
However, as far as compactness issues are concerned, I believe that a single fissure as in the previous example is not enough to contradict the Rellich-Kondrachov Theorem : $\Omega$ as above is the union of 4 Lipschitz domain (four small squares, in fact even 2 small squares and 1 rectangle would be enough) on which you can invoke each time Rellich-Kondrachov theorem and recover convergence (finite number of sequences implies common extraction).
If this " 4 pieces " argument is correct, this already tells you that the right assumptions on the boundary for the Rellich-Kondrachov are not necessarily the same as the one of the  extension theorems.
EDIT: Rellich-Kondrachov contains two statements : the embedding in $L^{p^\star}(\Omega)$ and the compact embedding in $L^q(\Omega)$ for $q<p^\star$. In the situation at stake in which $\Omega$ is not regular enough, the whole issue boils down to the first statement because we clearly have compact embedding in $L_{\text{loc}}^q(\Omega)$ (looking at balls contained in $\Omega$ there's no regularity issue) so for the second statement of the Rellich-Kondrachov theorem (compactness), we only need to check uniform integrability in $L^q(\Omega)$ (I focus here on the case when $\Omega$ is bounded) ; obviously this is true once the embedding in $L^{p^\star}(\Omega)$ is checked.
On the other hand, for a counterexample in which the embedding $W^{1,p}(\Omega)\hookrightarrow L^q(\Omega)$ is false for any $q>p$, you can check the book of Adams and Fournier, Theorem 4.48 (the relevant pathology is the exponential cusp, not the fissure). I would be interested to know if this counterexample can lead to a sequence $(f_n)_n$ bounded in $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ but not uniformly integrable in $L^p(\Omega)$ (and thus not compact).

So, do you know any relaxed results in the literature requiring less boundary smoothness?

Well if you just want less than Lipschitz you have the cone condition (again, check Adam and Fournier's book). However the fissure example does not satisfy the cone condition so I am a bit confused.
